# SharePoint Online Access Issues For Users Whose External Internet Access Is Limited By Company Policy

Tags: sharepoint-online

We are in the process of migrating SharePoint sites to Online.  We have a site on 2010 that is used by employees who have very limited external internet access.

Through our firewall, all employees should have access to the site:
.sharepoint.com*

We migrated the site to Online but have users who are having issues with the site.  They can open the site, but when they try to open content on it, lists for example, their browser just hangs or they get a blank white screen.

We are seeing this with folks who have no external access, aside from the above allowance.  Is this normal behavior or is there something we need to do to give them access to lists?  We are finding it odd that they can reach the site itself, but that's as far as they can get.  From what we can tell, the list urls are not taking them anywhere outside of the whitelisted environment.

Any thoughts or direction on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several IP Ranges and Urls that need to be accessible for SharePoint Online to be functional. Please follow [this article from microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/office365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges) and make sure the rules are setup correctly.